# Bengali encoding

Tags: character-encoding, converters, codepages

Does anybody know what encoding is this (in Bengali language):
Bs‡iRx eY©gvjvi cO_g eY©
‡fovi WvK, QvM‡ji e?v e?v WvK
‡Nvovi Mvwo; fvov‡U †gvUiMvwo

as an example this web site seems to use it:
http://www.shipbreakingbd.info
It's using it's own font to represent the contents, it's just an example. I got the text file in this encoding which I need to convert to UTF-8. How can I do it?

Comment: There's like a 101 plus ways to convert to UTF-8. What have you tried? Have you done any research? http://www.connect-bangladesh.org/bangla/webbangla.html and maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode is a good place to start

Comment: Converting itself and UTF-8 is not a problem, if I know FROM which encoding to convert. It doesn't seem to be ISCII 57003, and I don't know and didn't find any other Bengali encodings.

Comment: I'm going to bet the original was in unicode and more specifically UTF-8. When I copy the string of bengali characters from that site and paste it into my IDE set to utf8 it works peftectly. If I switch my IDE codepage to 1252 (ANSI - Latin I) in ascii I get garbage big string of question marks. I think if it is stored in the incorect encoding (something other than unicode) it is going to be lost.

Comment: Anthony, what IDE do you have? If it's possible to paste it into the IDE set to UTF-8, then it's possible just to save it in normal UTF-8 encoding :)

Comment: I think `<meta charset="unicode">` this line needs to be added on the `<head>` section to render `Bengali` language properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a glyph-based encoding used in Mustafa Jabbar's Bengali font series published from Dhaka. But this seems to be slight old an encoding. What you quoted in ASCII roughly translates to "The first letter of the English alphabet, sheep's baa baa, goat's maa maa, horse-driven carriage, motor car for hire." M Jabbar has changed his encoding several times, probably that is why the second character in the third word, which should be 'r' came out as 'ng' and the second characters in the eighth and ninth words, which should be 'y' came out as a question mark. It is certainly not in UTF-8.

Comment: I forgot to name the font, it is called Sutonny and a free version called Kalpurush ANSI is also available on the net.