# PHP send message from web to mobile

Tags: php

```
            $bsms="বাংলাদেশীদের জন্য ঈদ মানেই স্পেশাল খুশি। ";
            echo  $encodebangla=utf8_encode ($bsms );
            echo $a= utf8_decode($encodebangla);
            $sid='Shibly Test';
            $user = 'shiblyhelp';
            $pass = '123456';
            $num1="8801913884092";
            $cname="Shibly";
            $cgender="Mr.";
            $url="http:...................";
            $param="user=$user&pass=$pass&sms[0][0]=$num1&sms[0][1]=".utf8_decode($encodebangla)."&sms[1][2]=123456790&sid=$sid";
            $crl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
            curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
            curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
            curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
            curl_setopt($crl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$param);
            $response = curl_exec($crl);
            $xml = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($response)), 1);
```

This is my code. $bsms - this variable contains a bangla string. Now i want to send this string as a text msg of bangla to mobile. the msg has sent but i got. only ???????????????????????????? on my mobile message box. Please help me.

Comment: Please take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905727/bengali-encoding
If this isn't the solution for your problem specify your problem.

Comment: this link does not fulfill my requirement. Actually i want to get text message from my own website , which website sent me bangla text message. but when i wrote on bangla text message it send to mobile number but cant read that message which i have sent from web. because i got the text only ????????????????????????????.

Comment: So first of all you need to convert your string characters with this function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

The Encoding is Unicode. The Range for the Bengalic Chars is from U+0980 to U+09FF. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block

Comment: would you please write me the code???